# Specific order NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

Good day.

I have an NSMutableArray that contains references to objects. 
I need to rearrange the array so that each would-scanned object becomes the last in the array.

For example:

> The array has three links to three pictures.  Member and one looked
>   out, we save before exiting the index of images viewed
>
> The user has gone back into the program and he has shown a different
>   picture, the one that went beyond that which he looked
>
> A kind of carousel:)

Schematically as follows:

```
   {Store}      {look last}    {when reload} 
[0], [1], [2] -----> [1] ------> [2], [0], [1] 

[2], [0], [1] -----> [2] ------> [0], [1], [2]
```

i add object in cycle

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.myStorage count]; i++) {
    NSManagedObject *obj = [self.myStorage objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.myArray addObject: obj];
}
```

and reorder

```
int last = {get last from core data storage here}
for (int i = 0; i < [self.myArray count]; i++) {
    if(i != last) {
        [self.myArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:0];
    }    
}
```

That is right ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a total guess at what you're asking, but if you want to reorder the array by moving the object selected by the user to the front, then you can simply use the `NSMutableArray` methods `removeObjectAtIndex:` and `insertObject:atIndex:`. I'll elaborate further if you do.

Comment: You could also use `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[array objectAtIndex:givenIndex]];`

Comment: @EmptyStack this will create duplicates, not reorder

Comment: Yes. Really sorry! Actually I was about to write `[array exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:givenIndex];` I've lost my concentration ;-)